# Can't write to file in external DLL calls from VB6

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com, tlb

I am fixing some legacy VB6 code which needs to call an external COM .tlb .NET app from the VB6 program. The .NET app logs data to csv in an infinite loop, as well as uses the Trace to provide debug and error messages. If I test my external .NET logger on its own, it creates the data log files and runs flawlessly without errors of any kind. But when its called from the VB6 client it doesn't generate any of my log files, but it still runs in the loop forever.

I'm wondering what would cause the program to fail to create the files and begin logging.

I have enabled TRACE constant in the project settings

I always run as admin

I have searched every folder for the log files.

The DLL and TLB files are registered

I have tried saving the files to relative paths, no path, or `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);`
But none create the files

```
public string header = "Time,Channel1,Channel2,Channel3,Channel4,Channel5,Channel6,Channel7,Channel8,Channel9,Channel10,Channel11,Channel12,Channel13,Channel14,Channel15,Channel16\r\n";

Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("MemoTracelog " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt"));
Trace.AutoFlush = true;
try
{
    fs = new FileStream("MemoLog " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".csv" , FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    fs.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header), 0, header.Length);
}
catch (System.IO.IOException)
{
    WriteTraceLine("Couldn't open file for write. Use admin privileges and ensure file is not in use.");
}
```

```
public void WriteTraceLine(string whatToLog)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " " + whatToLog);
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " " + whatToLog);
}
```

No errors of any kind. Just runs, but doesn't create any files.

Comment: Have you closed the `FileStream`?

Comment: I close it when the class is signaled to terminate

Comment: You should enclose it in a `using` like this `using (var fs = new FileStream(...)) { fs.Write(...); ... }`. This ensures that it will be closed at the end of the [using statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I just tried that and still no luck. Running the .NET app works fine, but still no logs when calling from VB6

Comment: Try procmon tool from sysinternals, filter by your exe, you should see file API calls trace (success and failures).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about procmon before so this should be a helpful debug tool. 
I get a list of over 10 million calls from my VB6 app to my .NET interface, all seem to be success. These would be from my while loop, continuously reading data, which it is supposed to also write to log. 

I also know that the reads are successful because my VB6 app calls the .NET read function continually, and it gets back a boolean if it was successful, which it always is, but yet no logs :(

Comment: I had the same problem, but I found out, that it exists only if I run the app directly from VB6 Studio, if I run the compiled exe directly, then the file or log is written successfully. 
Of course, it took me two days and luck was involved as well :)